# Find the largest numbers stored in the each subarray's

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want the largest value from each of the subarray’s and push those values into a brand new array but the output return's empty array, I don’t know what’s wrong with this code.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
let newArr = []
for(let i=0; i<arr.lentgh; i++){
  newArr.push(Math.max(...arr[i]))
}
return newArr;
}

let largest = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: `length` spelling matters.

Comment: Its a typo, you wrote lentgh

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
let largestSub = (arr) => [...arr.map(e => Math.max(...e))]

let result = largestSub([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function works correctly for me, but If I was to rewrite it:

I would advise you to map the array instead of a loop.
Something like:

```js
function maxOf(arr) {
  return arr.map(sa => Math.max(...sa))
}
```

EDIT: you have a typo, it should be `length` not `lentgh`